# Resize video in PyQt

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, video-player

I am building a video player using PyQt and OpenCV. Using a separate thread I read a video file with OpenCV and then send it to the DisplayFrame class that uses the paint event to display each frame.

My question is how can I make the video resize like VLC Player? Rendering black empty space around the video if the player window is to wide or high and resizing the player window and keeping the video proportions the same?

Class used for displaying frames:

```
class DisplayFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisplayFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.image = QImage()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        self.image = QImage()

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def set_image(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must adjust the size of the image to the size of the window. To do this you must change:

```
painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
```

to:

```
painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. What else do I need to change if I want to prevent the image to get stretched (to maintain the aspect ration)?

Comment: You can use the `resize()` method or something similar. If my answer helps, mark it as correct please

Comment: Do you want it to stretch only proportional to the size of the image?

Comment: Yes, and if the user stretches the window to a size that is not proportial to the image it wouldn't stretch the image.